# selenium grid Safari alternative (Docker nodes)?

Tags: selenium

I'm running a selenium grid on kubernetes. Currently I have 3 FF/Chrome nodes running on docker: https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-chrome/ and 
https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-firefox/

that are connected to my hub.

what can I use for safari? Would any webkit based browser be ok? and if so, would I have to create a docker image for that one myself.